# Can Spring Cloud Gateway map a single request to two downstream services?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

The background is my application needs to insert an user input into two databases, which are MongoDB and  Elasticsearch. There are already two database-level services with save function.

Now I am working on an experiment to duplicate a single request to two downstream database services. 
I have tried using Spring Cloud Gateway with routes, it can route a request to either MongoDB or Elasticsearch.

If the route to MongoDB is placed advanced of that to Elasticsearch, then Spring Cloud Gateway routes the request to MongoDB. The route to Elasticsearch is ignored even it has the same predicates with MongoDB's. And vice versa.

Here is the configuration in Yaml. Can anyone advise if duplicating a request is doable or not in Spring Cloud Gateway ? Thanks.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:

      - id: http-others-route-to-mongo
        uri: http://localhost:9064/
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/**
        - Method=POST,PUT,DELETE
        - Between=2020-01-15T23:59:59.000+08:00[Asia/Shanghai], 2100-12-31T23:59:59.000+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]

      - id: http-others-route-to-es
        uri: http://localhost:9037/
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/**
        - Method=POST,PUT,DELETE
        - Between=2020-01-15T23:59:59.000+08:00[Asia/Shanghai], 2100-12-31T23:59:59.000+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]
```

Comment: It is not possible